# Engines de JavaScript atuais poderiam otimizar chamadas recursivas "em cauda"?

Tags: javascript, desempenho, funções, recursão

Em [programação funcional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-funcional/info), é muito comum o uso de funções [recursivas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/recurs%C3%A3o/info). Certas linguagens, como Scheme, sequer possuem estruturas de controle para loops, dependendo de recursão para iterar sobre listas.

JavaScript possui características funcionais, como funções de primeira classe, mas apresenta restrições quanto ao uso da recursão. Por exemplo:

```
function fatorial(num) {
    if (num === 0) { 
        return 1; 
    }
    return num * fatorial(num - 1);
}
fatorial(5);      // 120
fatorial(100000); // RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

<sup>Favor ignorar o fato de que `fatorial(100000)` é um número que JavaScript sequer é capaz de representar.</sup>

Se a quantidade de recursões ultrapassar um certo limite, o *engine* não é capaz de processar o resultado, lançando um erro ou travando o programa. Isso ocorre porque o tamanho da pilha de chamada (que armazena o contexto de execução de cada invocação da função – o que inclui variáveis locais e a referência ao escopo "pai" da função, base do mecanismo das *closures*) tem um tamanho fixo. E esse limite existe para garantir que a pilha de chamada não consuma memória em excesso.

Há porém uma técnica para se evitar essa limitação, dependendo de como o código da função estiver estruturado. Se a chamada recursiva estiver em [posição "de cauda"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)#Fun.C3.A7.C3.B5es_recursivas_em_cauda), ou seja, for a última instrução da função, seu contexto de execução é dispensável, pois é garantido que a função não precisará mais dele quando as chamadas recursivas forem desempilhadas. Assim, é possível limpar ou "reciclar" o quadro (*frame*) da pilha utilizado pelo contexto de execução da função que está em execução, e utilizá-lo para a chamada recursiva, de modo que uma função recursiva em cauda acaba  utilizando um único quadro de pilha para toda a operação. Essa técnica é conhecida como otimização de chamada em cauda (*tail call optimization*).

#### Pergunta

Apesar dessa técnica ser amplamente conhecida, nenhum engine de JavaScript parece utilizá-la, seja no interpretador em si, seja como parte das operações efetuadas pelos compiladores JIT que todos os engines modernos utilizam. A pergunta é, por quê? Existe alguma restrição na linguagem que torna essa otimização impossível? Ou talvez ela seja possível, mas custosa demais?

A gramática da próxima versão da linguagem (ECMAScript 6, ainda em rascunho) inclui verificações para a posição de cauda, prevendo esse tipo de otimização. Porém, não me parece que a falta disso na versão atual impediria que a técnica fosse utilizada já hoje.

Comment: bfavaretto também foi mordido pelo mosquito da tradução literal :)

Comment: Quase criei uma tag "otimização-de-recursão-em-cauda", mas ultrapassa o máximo permitido de 25 caracteres :)

Comment: Recursão em "calda"... deu vontade de comer uma sobremesa ;)

Comment: Uai, "recursão em cauda" é um termo comumente utilizado, não uma tradução literal. Ainda se fosse "recursão no rabo"...

Comment: Mas também calcular 100000! é demais. Em nenhuma situação você vai precisar disso. Para ter ideia o resultado é 2.82422940796034787429342157802453551847749492 × 10^456573.

Comment: @GabrielSantos Foi só um exemplo! Repare que eu mesmo disse, em letras miúdas, que o resultado nem é representável como Number em js. O fato é que esses erros de stack overflow ocorrem quando se usa recursão intensivamente, o que é comum em programação funcional.

Comment: 6 anos depois e até hoje não implementaram isso no JavaScript. Parece que vai ficar no papel do ECMAScript para sempre... Lamentável.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar quero salientar uma importante diferença de termos:

- **Tail Call Optimization:** Quando uma implementação otimiza uma chamada em cauda de forma que um novo *stack frame* não seja alocado e o *caller* seja utilizado, criando um acrescimo zero de memoria. Repare que isso é uma otimização, ou seja, é opcional e não se deve assumir que acontecerá. Ela alterá o comportamento do programa fazendo-o consumir menos memoria e potencialmente criando loops infinitos.
- **"Proper Tail Call":** Uma característica da linguagem que **garante** que a "otimização" acontecerá. Nesse caso uma implementação que consuma memoria linearmente ou provoque um `RangeError` é inválida. Isso requer especificação por parte da linguagem para definir o formato exato que a função deve ser escrita.

A otimização de chamada recursiva sempre foi possível, mas nunca foi propriamente implementada por nenhuma engine conhecida (exceto o [Rhino](http://wiki.apache.org/cocoon/RhinoWithContinuations), como o utluiz mencionou). Não há nada na linguagem que proiba essa otimização. `<function>.caller` pode ser passado como se fosse um argumento a cada chamada e `<function>.arguments` pode ser parte da stack. Muito me impressiona o fato de ninguém suportar essa otimização, mas não há argumentos contrários. Talvez apenas o esforço de engenharia envolvido que não valha a pequena quantidade de usos. Ou a coleta do stack frame para caso ocorra uma exception.

O "Proper Tail Call" está nos [planos para o ECMAScript 6](https://wiki.mozilla.org/ES6_plans#New_syntax_.28stuff_that_affects_the_front_end_and.2For_bytecode.29) e, se não for removido até o lançamento (que deve ocorrer ainda este ano), deverá ser suportado por todos os grandes navegadores e engines em meados de 2015.

O [Continuum](https://github.com/Benvie/continuum), uma implementação do ES6 escrita no ES3, já [tem suporte para isso](http://bbenvie.com/articles/2013-01-06/JavaScript-ES6-Has-Tail-Call-Optimization):

```html
<html>
  <script src="https://rawgithub.com/Benvie/continuum/gh-pages/continuum.js"></script>
  <script>
    var realm = continuum.createRealm();
    realm.evaluate("function fac(n, accum){return n > 0 ? fac(n - 1, n * accum) : accum;}");
    // pode demorar um pouco
    console.log("fac(100000) = " + realm.evaluate("fac(100000, 1)"));
    // mas eventualmente chegará na resposta: Infinity :)
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Parece que a resposta é mais simples do que eu imaginava, então. Simplesmente não implementaram porque não quiseram (já que hoje poderiam implementar como TCO mesmo). Eu já vi esses argumentos de que `<function>.caller` e `<function>.arguments` seriam impeditivos, e isso nunca me convenceu – mesmo que fosse verdade, seria possível otimizar código que rode em strict mode.

Comment: Não consigo ver um único motivo que faça o uso dessas funções impedir a otimização. Ainda assim seria possivel analisar e excluir código que potencialmente os use. Como disse, estou surpreso que isso não seja já feito. Talvez seja uma construção pouco usada.

Answer (score 6):

Bem, eu não entendo profundamente de compiladores ou interpretadores, portanto vou me ater aos fatos que encontrei em documentações e referências.

Em tese, Javascript *poderia* ter a otimização de chamadas "em cauda". De fato, existe uma implementação especial que já possui este recurso: [RhynoWithContinuations](http://wiki.apache.org/cocoon/RhinoWithContinuations). Esta é uma versão do Rhyno, uma implementação Javascript feita 100% em Java.

Quanto ao padrão ECMAScript, lendo alguns detalhes [aqui](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproper_tail_calls) e [aqui](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=proposals%3aproper_tail_calls), o que eu pude entender foi que *proper tail calls*, como eles chamam *tail call optimization*, não consiste apenas em uma mera otimização, mas num aspecto semântico importante da linguagem. Então um padrão que imponha certas restrições é necessário, pois se cada implementação da linguagem aplicasse suas próprias regras, códigos que se utilizassem desse recurso não seriam portáveis.

Além disso, conforme citado no penúltimo link, parece haver uma dificuldade com alguns recursos da linguagem, como a possibilidade de acessar os argumentos (`<function>.arguments`), quem chamou a função (`<function>.caller`) e outros. Em suma, implementar a otimização e recursão em cauda iria afetar a pilha de chamadas da função. Este é um dos motivos da [documentação mais atual](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-tail-position-calls) afirmar que a otimização será aplicada somente em *strict mode*, pois este modo proíbe o uso desses recursos.

Finalmente, há uma discussão muito interessante ([aqui](http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/162tth/javascript_es6_has_tail_call_optimization/)), baseada no artigo "[*JavaScript (ES6) Has Tail Call Optimization*](http://bbenvie.com/articles/2013-01-06/JavaScript-ES6-Has-Tail-Call-Optimization)", onde o autor afirma que o motivo para ainda não haver este recurso na linguagem é o mesmo de vários outros: uma questão de prioridades.

Comment: Eu entendo que esta resposta é superficial. Porém, achei a questão muito interessante e resolvi pesquisar. De qualquer forma, ela já está favoritada!

Comment: Eu não sabia que já havia uma implementação com isso, obrigado pelo link! Quanto aos *proper tail calls*, não tenho certeza de que serão implementados como proposto inicialmente. Pelo menos aquela gramática de atributos (que não entendo direito) [parece não estar sendo usada](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-tail-position-calls). Espero que alguém consiga me explicar o motivo em detalhes, essa pergunta está na minha cabeça há meses!

Comment: Ótimo recurso, mas é bom mencionar que esse link se trata de uma **extensão** do Rhino (plugin, implementação alternativa, não entendi bem) chamada ["Cocoon"](http://wiki.apache.org/cocoon/FrontPage). O [Rhino original](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino) (desenvolvido pela Mozilla) não oferece suporte a essa funcionalidade.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Certo, ajustei a resposta para esclarecer isso.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu atualizei a resposta com algumas informações a mais que descobri. Só não entendi a qual "gramática de atributos" você está se referindo.

Comment: Eu vi, acabei de ler a discussão no reddit, vale a pena mesmo. O artigo eu tinha lido, mas a discussão não. A gramática de atributos ocupa metade da proposta dos proper tail call que você linkou (http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproper_tail_calls)

Comment: @bfavaretto Ah tá. Realmente parece que eles abandonaram o formato da proposta inicial por atributos de gramática por uma espécie de pseudo-código misturado com gramática que determina se o trecho atende os requisitos de ser uma "cauda" (itens 14.6.1 e 14.6.2). O item 14.6.3 define o que será feito com o contexto de execução.