# Como lidar com "grandes iterações" usando recursão?

Tags: javascript, recursão, programação-funcional

No contexto da programação funcional, diz-se que qualquer tipo de laço de repetição (como `for` ou `while`) devem ser deixados de lado, em favor da recursão.

Mas conforme o número de elementos do trabalho começa a crescer, a recursividade pode perder para os laços de repetição mais imperativos, uma vez que eles não sofrem com o problema da *call stack*.

É possível resolver esse problema? Como, na programação funcional, se lida com a iteração de uma grande quantidade de dados, em JavaScript?

Ouvi dizer de "*tail call optimisation*", mas me parece que esse recurso ainda não é suportado, conforme mostrado no [Node.Green](https://node.green/).

[image: Tabela de suporte a tail call optimisation no Node.green]

Comment: Talvez ajude: https://www.sitepoint.com/recursion-functional-javascript/

Comment: PS: Apesar de parecidas, a minha pergunta é diferente [desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2467/engines-de-javascript-atuais-poderiam-otimizar-chamadas-recursivas-em-cauda?rq=1). Isso porque a minha pergunta se há uma forma de contornar esse problema, mesmo sem a otimização (ainda não implementada) da especificação do ECMAScript 2015 (ES6).

Comment: Vale lembrar que [nem todos os algoritmos recursivos são "de cauda"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4282/112052) e o *tail call optmization* só é aplicável aos que são. Até [existem maneiras](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/66353) de converter uma recursão para que use *tail calls*, mas se está lidando com grande quantidade de dados que vão com certeza estourar o *stack*, uma alternativa talvez seja simplesmente não usar recursão :-) Eu raramente uso, então não sei se existe alguma solução mirabolante para grandes volumes de dados...

Comment: Não sei se dá para responder isso a não ser com um "não use recursão em linguagens que não foram feitas para isto". A otimização de cauda é fundamental para aceitar recursão que não vá além do trivial. Se a linguagem suporta então não há esse problema, desde que a recursão seja de cauda.

Comment: "É possível resolver isso"? Bem, toda solução que eu conheço para isso faz iteração em elementos de uma pilha, imperativamente. Isso transforma a lógica de recursão de "callstack" para jogar as variáveis num objeto adequado de pilha

Answer (score -3):

Você levantou um ponto importante! A recursão, apesar de elegante e conceitualmente poderosa na programação funcional, pode enfrentar problemas de desempenho quando lidamos com grandes volumes de dados, devido ao problema da pilha de chamadas.

A Tail Call Optimization (TCO) é uma técnica que otimiza certos tipos de recursões ao evitar o crescimento ilimitado da pilha de chamadas. Infelizmente, nem todas as implementações de linguagens de programação suportam essa otimização.

No caso do JavaScript, a TCO não é uma garantia em todas as situações, apesar de estar especificada no ECMAScript 6. Além disso, como você mencionou, nem todas as implementações ou ambientes (como o Node.js) podem suportar a TCO de forma consistente.

Então, como lidar com grandes iterações na programação funcional em JavaScript quando a recursão se torna ineficiente?

Uso prudente da recursão: Para conjuntos de dados pequenos ou médios, a recursão pode ser uma abordagem elegante e funcional. É útil quando a quantidade de chamadas recursivas não é excessiva.

Iteradores e funções de ordem superior: JavaScript possui métodos de iteradores como map, reduce, filter e forEach que são extremamente poderosos e adequados para lidar com grandes volumes de dados de forma mais eficiente. Essas funções são parte do paradigma funcional e podem substituir muitos loops tradicionais.

Bibliotecas externas: Bibliotecas como o Lodash ou Ramda oferecem métodos que trabalham com listas e coleções de forma funcional e eficiente. Eles têm implementações otimizadas para operações em grande escala.

Divisão e conquista: Em alguns casos, é possível dividir o problema em partes menores, processá-las e combinar os resultados, reduzindo assim a carga recursiva.

Considerar alternativas imperativas: Em situações onde a eficiência é crítica e a recursão não é a melhor opção, pode ser justificado utilizar métodos mais imperativos, como loops (for, while) para lidar com grandes volumes de dados.

Em resumo, enquanto a recursão é elegante e poderosa na programação funcional, em JavaScript é importante considerar o contexto e o volume de dados ao escolher a abordagem mais adequada. Em casos de grandes iterações, métodos de alto desempenho, como iteradores, podem ser preferíveis à recursão.

Comment: Eu havia dado o positivo. Mas depois de ler sua outra resposta GPT não posso mais sustentar esse voto

Answer (score -4):

No contexto da programação funcional, em especial no Javascript, geralmente se usa as funções iteradoras. Por exemplo, em um array e um objeto:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

numbers.forEach(num => console.log(num));

const doubledNumbers = numbers.map(num => num * 2);

const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(key, value));
```

Geralmente, na prática, no contexto do Javascript, não se usa tanto a recursão, justamente porque a memória não é infinita nem temos tail call optimization; usamos então iteradores que já estão embutidos na linguagem pois eles são parecidos com os formatos imperativos `for` e `while`.

Comment: Não é isso. Sei que a pergunta é bastante técnica, e por isso a dificuldade em a compreender, mas o autor da pergunta quer saber sobre a otimização de funções recursivas como emulação de recursão em cauda(tail call), regra do trampolim(Trampoline Rule) e bifurcação de execução em Y(Y Fork) que são mecanismos para reduzir o consumo de memória e minimizar as limitações do uso de pilhas de chamadas impostas por linguagens de paradigma não funcional.