# Como somar de 1 a número usando o comando "for" sendo o número N um parâmetro de função?

Tags: javascript, funções, for

Sendo `n` o valor de `5`, somando `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5`, saindo resultado no `return`.

Tentei fazer assim, mas não deu certo:

```
function (n){

for ( var i = 0; i < n.length; i++ ){
   total += n[i];
}

return total;
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara. O parâmetro `n` é um número (como diz o texto da pergunta) ou um array? Porque você está fazendo `n[i]` — indicando que `n` seria um array (ou objeto)?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 7):

Imagino que pegou algum código pronto que varre uma coleção de dados que soma seus valores. Aprender baseando-se em códigos prontos é muito popular, mas também é o motivo porque as pessoas não entendem o que está acontecendo ali, e programação é justamente entender oque está acontecendo.

Então o que deseja não é percorrer uma coleção, é percorrer uma sequência numérica, não tem que ter um *array* como foi usado. Você apenas tem que contar sem o acesso à *array* algum. E claro, deve ir acumulando o valor em cada passo, como o fez.

Nem seria possível pegar o `length` de `n`porque `n` não tem um tamanho, ele é só um número muito simples, quem tem tamanho são coleções de dados.

Tem outros erros. Um deles é que não inicializou a variável acumuladora. Até funciona, mas é gambiarra.

Outro é que a função não tem nome.

E finalmente não pode comece do 0, pelo descrito deve começar do 1 a vai até o número passado, inclusive. Esse erros é consequência de usar a ideia do acesso ao *array* que realmente começa do 0 e termina no número passado, de forma exclusiva.

```js
function acumula(n) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) total += i;
    return total;
}
console.log(acumula(5));
```

Mas não precisa de nada disso, pode usar [pura matemática](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress%C3%A3o_aritm%C3%A9tica#Soma_dos_termos_de_uma_progress%C3%A3o_aritm%C3%A9tica) e dar o resultado sem um laço.

```js
function acumula(n) {
    return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}
console.log(acumula(5));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Math/SumProgression.js).

Comment: Essa ultima é uma função fatorial, não é? poderia ser escrita como `function acumula(n) {
 if (n == 0) return n;
 return acumula(n - 1) + n;
}` desta forma, usando recursividade?

Comment: Isso que você fez substitui o primeiro código, que é que muito mais complicado e ineficiente que meu segundo.

Comment: A sim. Entendi. Por causa da recusividade, esta funcao teria mais custo de processamento.

Comment: @CmteCardeal, além disso, o JavaScript (atualmente) tem um limite para o número máximo de chamadas na _call stack_, então, a depender do número que o cara passar, o JS nem vai conseguir executar com êxito. Fiz uma [pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/427564/69296) há um tempo, mas sem resposta.

Comment: @LuizFelipe a não ser que tenha um limite artificial é pra ser um número bem grande porque seria só o problema do estouro da pilha.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Entendi seu ponto, acho que se tratando de JS, cheguei a conclusão que, mesmo eu gostando de programação funcional, ela nem sempre atende a todas as situações. Agora graças ao seu comentário, aprendi que as vezes uma forma impertiva se sobresai em relação a PF, pois confesso que não sabia desse problema de *call stack* para funções recursivas. Nesse caso acho que entra a experiência de cada desenvolvedor em escolher qual e melhor forma de resolver um problema de forma eficiente :)